# Cannot set property 'imgId' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to node.js and trying to save photos of users into mongodb.

Here is the router:

```
  router.post('/addphoto',  checkAuth, upload.single('image'), (req, res)=> {

   let filename = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)
   console.log('imgId is', filename  );

      const photoFields = {};
      photoFields.photos = []
    if(req.file) photoFields.image = req.file.path ;
    photoFields.user = req.user.id; 

    Photo.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }).then(photo => {
          if(photo) {
        //Update

        console.log('photo found! \n\n');
        Photo.findOneAndUpdate(
          {user: req.user.id},
          {$set: photoFields},
          {new: true}
          ).then(photo => res.json(photo));
      } else {
        console.log('No photo found! \n\n');
        //Create
        photoFields.photos[0].imgId =  filename  ;
        photoFields.photos[0].isProfileImg =  true  ;
        photoFields.photos[0].visible = 'all';


        //Save
        new Photo(photoFields).save().then(photo=> {
            res.json(photo);
        }).catch(err => {
              console.log('could not save photo \n\n');
              console.log(err);
        }

      );
  }
    }) 
  });
```

Each user can upload several photos so here is the photo schema in which photos is an array of objects:

```
  const PhotoSchema = new Schema({

    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'users'
    }, 

  photos: [
    {
      imgId: {
        type: Number,
      },
      isProfileImg: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
      },
      visible: {
        type: String,
      }
    }
  ]

});
```

As you can see I create imgId using random function, and I can see that it is created:

```
imgId is 65609
```

However, I still get this error in the console:

```
(node:5295) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'imgId' of undefined
```

And no image is saved.

I'm using multer to extract file from request post and I can set in the console that file is being received.

I appreciate your hints to fix this error which bugs me for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You set the `imgId` in one place, in the else clause where no photo is found,
in the statement

```
photoFields.photos[0].imgId = filename ;
```

The list `photoFields.photos` is empty, so the first element 
`photoFields.photos[0]`is `undefined`.

Do something like this instead.

```
photoFields.photos.push({
    imgId: filename,
    isProfileImg: true,
    visible: 'all',
})
```

Comment: When photo is crated for the first time `photoFields.photos[0]` does not exist.  Please complete your answer, as I'm not sure how to use your tip.